# SQLAlchemy raw SQL Query NoSuchColumnError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a relatively complex sql statement that I want to execute with sqlalchemy ORM. But when I try to do so I always get the error `{NoSuchColumnError}"Could not locate column in row for column 'transaction_out.value'"`. My sql statement looks as follows:

```
sql = """
Select
    addresses.address,
    transaction_out1.value As sent,
    transaction_out1.transaction_id As sent_id,
    transactions.block As block_sent,
    transactions.time As time_sent,
    transactions.txid As txid_sent,
    "sent" as type
From
    transaction_out INNER Join
    transaction_out_address On transaction_out_address.transaction_out_id = transaction_out.id INNER Join
    addresses On transaction_out_address.address_id = addresses.id INNER Join
    transaction_in On transaction_in.transaction_out_id = transaction_out.id INNER Join
    transactions On transaction_in.transaction_id = transactions.id INNER Join
    transaction_out transaction_out1 On transaction_out1.transaction_id = transactions.id INNER Join
    transactions transactions1 On transaction_out.transaction_id = transactions1.id
WHERE addresses.address=:address_string
UNION
Select
    addresses.address,
    transaction_out.value As received,
    transaction_out.transaction_id As received_id,
    transactions.block As received_block,
    transactions.time As received_time,
    transactions.txid As received_txid,
    "received"
From
    transaction_out LEFT Join
    transaction_out_address On transaction_out_address.transaction_out_id = transaction_out.id LEFT Join
    addresses On transaction_out_address.address_id = addresses.id LEFT Join
    transaction_in On transaction_in.transaction_out_id = transaction_out.id LEFT Join
    transactions On transaction_out.transaction_id = transactions.id
WHERE addresses.address=:address_string
"""
```

And I tried to execute the statement in the following way:

```
query = session.query(Address.address, TransactionOut.value, TransactionOut.id, Block.height, Transaction.time, Transaction.txid).from_statement(
        stmt.bindparams(
            bindparam("address_string",
            value=address_string)
))
```

I can execute the raw sql statement with `engine.execute()` without any problems but I need to do it with `session.query()` so I can use sqlalchemy-datatables. My database looks more or less like the one here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137791/blockchain-bitcoin-as-a-database/137800#137800.

What is the problem with the way I try to execute it?

Comment: Did you try running the query directly against the database? Looks like a SQL error

Comment: @kjmerf Yes I just tried it again. It runs perfectly fine from the mysql console.

Comment: Turn the engine logging on (`echo=True`) and inspect the difference between the query that you know works, and the one that sqlalchemy is generating.

Comment: @IljaEverilä How can I make it aliased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column aliases in the raw SQL are hiding the columns from the SQLAlchemy query. Either remove them, or alter the query to accommodate them:

```
query = session.query(Address.address,
                      TransactionOut.value.label('sent'),
                      TransactionOut.id.label('sent_id'),
                      Transaction.block.label('block_sent'),
                      Transaction.time.label('time_sent'),
                      Transaction.txid.label('txid_sent')).\
    from_statement(stmt).\
    params(address_string=address_string)
```