# SQL sqlalchemy inner join error: "Could not locate column in row for column 'xxxx.id'"

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, inner-join

Schematically: I have these tables [columns]

```
Flights [id, date, user_id, club_id, etc]
Clubs [id, etc]
Users [id, name, club_id, etc]
```

I can find the number of flights for each user, the number of flights for each club, etc.

The challenging part for me is to find the number of (unique) users in each club that submitted flights in the database.  I'm pretty sure that the starting point is

```
SELECT flights.club_id, users.name FROM flights
INNER JOIN users ON flights.club_id=users.club_id
```

and then do a `count` on this.

But I've tried to implement the above query join with sqlalchemy functions (v1.3.1) and with "text", e.g.

```
    query = db.session.query(Flight,User).from_statement(\
                  text('''SELECT flights.club_id, users.first_name FROM flights
                           INNER JOIN users ON flights.club_id=users.club_id  '''))
```

...I get this error from either method:

```
"Could not locate column in row for column 'flights.id'"
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?  I see very little online about this error.

Or is there a better way to get the number of users in each club that have flights in the database?

---

Here is the full error trace:

```
  File "/home/bret/pycharm/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/bret/.local/share/virtualenvs/skylinesC-0VgGNjgC/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3186, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/home/bret/.local/share/virtualenvs/skylinesC-0VgGNjgC/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 105, in instances
    util.raise_from_cause(err)
  File "/home/bret/.local/share/virtualenvs/skylinesC-0VgGNjgC/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/home/bret/.local/share/virtualenvs/skylinesC-0VgGNjgC/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 89, in instances
    for row in fetch
  File "/home/bret/.local/share/virtualenvs/skylinesC-0VgGNjgC/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 508, in _instance
    tuple([row[column] for column in pk_cols]),
  File "/home/bret/.local/share/virtualenvs/skylinesC-0VgGNjgC/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 627, in _key_fallback
    % expression._string_or_unprintable(key)
NoSuchColumnError: "Could not locate column in row for column 'flights.id'"
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: When you get a result that you don't expect, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first unexpected subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.) Ask about that. Just ask 1 (clear researched specific) question per post. PS Print the actual query string you are passing.

Comment: I'm still interested in learning more about the error "Could not locate column in row for column 'flights.id'"

Comment: Sorry @philipxy the model code is too long and complex to post.  I did quote the actual query string I posted in the "query = ... " line.  I'm pretty sure the query string would be valid for simpler model code, and suspect the problem is elsewhere...wondering if others have run across this error.

Comment: You didn't post the actual query string executed. You posted code that evaluates an expression & calls an api via another language. Also your error message talks about a column flights.id but there's no such expression in the given code. You may have a view or the error may come from running different code. It doesn't matter what your model code is, you should give as much of a [mre] as possible & look at what happening in each layer & is passed between them. PS It's of course extremely unlikely that you are the only person to ever get this error.

Comment: "I'm still interested in learning more about the error" Before you wrote that I already commented specifically to say that if you want to know about that then post a question that asks about that. This post asks 2 questions. Ask 1 question per post. And if you want that question answered you need to give more of a MRE. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers.

Comment: Googling 'site:stackoverflow.com sqlalchemy NoSuchColumnError: "Could not locate column in row for column" not in query' we immediately hit things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57821668/3404097). Notice the comments & answer talking about examining what is going on in & between layers. (Your problem may well be per that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count the unique users for the clubs in the Flights table. For the count you don't need to join tables. At least if the assumption holds, that the "user_id, club_id" pairs in the FLights table are correct. The query can look like this:

```
uniquesum = db.session.query(Flights.club_id, 
   func.count((Flights.user_id.distinct())).label('countusers') ).group_by(Flights.club_id)
```

This returns only two columns: Club(s) id and the count. If you need more information from Clubs table, you can join these tables to get something such as the Clubs name...

Comment: Thanks Andi!  That worked great. For my notes, this translates into "SELECT flights.club_id AS flights_club_id, count(DISTINCT flights.pilot_id) AS countusers FROM flights GROUP BY flights.club_id"